# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

I'm enumerating through a Dictionary and creating an item to be added to a ListView. However, one line in particular is causing this error:

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> s in test.Value.Properties)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = String.Format("{0}", s.Key);
    if (s.Value) { item.Checked = true; } // the problem line
    listView2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I assume the reason why setting the item.Text works is because I'm not modifying the original value since it's creating a new string. If I change item.Checked = true to create a new boolean, it works fine but the boolean is always defaulted to false which is not what I want.

How can I work around this problem?

Also, should I not be trying to modify *any* collection's data in a foreach? I originally thought the issue was because I was modifying the collection's data that I'm looping through, but this seems to be an issue with the ListViewItemCollection, which I'm not looping through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is only raised if you modify the collection you are enumerating through.
I can't see anything like that in your code, so there must be some other problem.
I can only guess, but maybe, you modify `test.Value.Properties` in an event that is raised when you add a new item to the `listView2`?

Comment: This was the answer I was writing. The OP is making no changes to s or to test.Value.Properties, which is the usual culprit for this type of exception.

Comment: Ah, that's it. I had an ItemCheck method on listView2 that's modifying the collection I'm looping through. Haven't found a solution but at least I found the culprit. Thank you!